# Choosing numbers without replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, conditional-probability

What  is the probability of choosing 4 numbers from a bag of numbers from 1-10 without replacement, so that the smallest number choosen is 4?

I was thinking $\left(\frac{7}{10}\cdot\frac{6}{9}\cdot\frac{5}{8}\cdot\frac{4}{7}\right)$.

Is it correct or am I wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I see what you're going for insofar as "okay, I have $7$ available choices on my first draw, so it's $7/10$, and I have $6$ on my second so $6/9$," and so on. However, what if I were to draw $7,8,9,10$? This would be valid under your calculation, but it's not what the problem desires. You need to better account for the "the smallest number is $4$"

Comment: Sorry @EeveeTrainer, I didn't understand what you said. Can you please explain?

Comment: You *have* to draw a $4$.  In yours it's possible everything you draw is bigger tthan a $4$.  You must do that you Have to draw a $4$ and $4$ is the smallest thing you draw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After $4$ is fixed, the remaining three numbers have to be from $5$ to $10$ inclusive. So the number of draws whose smallest number is $4$ is the number of draws from $5$ to $10$, or $\displaystyle\binom{6}{3}=20$. Then the desired probability follows as $\frac{20}{\displaystyle\binom{10}{4}}=\frac{20}{210}=\frac2{21}$.